# Simulate Ctrl-C keyboard interrupt in Python while working in Linux

Tags: python, linux, kill

I am working on some scripts (in the company I work in) that are loaded/unloaded into hypervisors to fire a piece of code when an event occurs. The only way to actually unload a script is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. I am writing a function in Python that automates the process

As soon as it sees the string `"done"` in the output of the program, it should kill the `vprobe`.
I am using `subprocess.Popen` to execute the command:

```
lineList = buff.readlines()
cmd = "vprobe /vprobe/myhello.emt"
p = subprocess.Popen(args = cmd, shell=True,stdout = buff, universal_newlines = True,preexec_fn=os.setsid)
while not re.search("done",lineList[-1]):
        print "waiting"
os.kill(p.pid,signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

As you can see, I am writing the output in `buff` file descriptor opened in read+write mode. I check the last line; if it has `'done'`, I kill it. Unfortunately, the `CTRL_C_EVENT` is only valid for Windows.
What can I do for Linux?

Comment: FYI: `re.search` with a constant string can be better expressed as `while 'done' not in lineList[-1]: ...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can just send the Linux equivalent, `signal.SIGINT` (the interrupt signal).

(Edit: I used to have something here discouraging the use of this strategy for controlling subprocesses, but on more careful reading it sounds like you've already decided you need control-C in this specific case...  So, SIGINT should do it.)

Comment: hey Andrew. Thanks for the answer. But actually, the SIGINT kills only the subprocess function while the vprobe continues it's execution.Do you have an idea of how to kill that too? Thanks

Comment: Well, if it works on Windows, then hopefully that means the signal is going to the right place.  So, try something stronger.  Give SIGTERM a try, and if that doesn't work, SIGKLL.  If SIGKILL doesn't work, then nothing will -- you'll have to look at different ways of handling the subprocess altogether.

Comment: Did you try `Popen(['vprobe ', '/vprobe/myhello.emt'], shell=False, ...)`? @Core_Dumped

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I misunderstand something, but the way you do it it is difficult to get the desired result.

Whatever `buff` is, you query it first, then use it in the context of `Popen()` and then you hope that by maciv `lineList` fills itself up.

What you probably want is something like

```
logfile = open("mylogfile", "a")
p = subprocess.Popen(['vprobe', '/vprobe/myhello.emt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  buff, universal_newlines=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
for line in p.stdout:
    logfile.write(line)
    if re.search("done", line):
        break
    print "waiting"
os.kill(p.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

This gives you a pipe end fed by your `vprobe` script which you can read out linewise and act appropriately upon the found output.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want to do,except that I want the output to get printed in some file as well (along with getting into the PIPE for checking purposes). How can I do that? (I hope I am grammatically correct this time :))

Comment: The above code seems well and good but when I use the stdout as an attribute of the object p, it gives me Broken PIPE error.

Comment: @Core_Dumped Where exactly do you get that? At the sending side (in `vprobe`), or in your own program?

Comment: cmd = "/sbin/vprobe /vprobe/myhello.emt"
p = subprocess.Popen(args = cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
print p.stdout

gives:

<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0xffd36758>
vprobe: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: This is clear. You don't read the `p.stdout` as provided in my answer, and when the reading side of the pipe dies, `vprobe` gets a `SIGPIPE`. You should do as written in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18456/discussion-between-core-dumped-and-glglgl)

Answer (score 5):

In Linux, Ctrl-C keyboard interrupt can be sent programmatically to a process using Popen.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) function. For example

```
import subprocess
import signal

..
process = subprocess.Popen(..)
..
process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
..
```

Don't use Popen.communicate() for blocking commands..