# Catching Terminal Output in Python

Tags: python, terminal, output

I want to do something similar to the second answer here (but not quite similar): [Simulate Ctrl-C keyboard interrupt in Python while working in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024532/simulate-ctrl-c-keyboard-interrupt-in-python-while-working-in-linux)

It's much simpler and I think I'm just missing something. Say, from a python script, I just want to call 'ping' and terminate it after the 10th time. I'm trying to do it like from the link above:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', 'google.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
  print line
  if re.search('10', line):
    break
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

But it doesn't work.

And I also want the regular output of 'ping' to be displayed. How do I do this?

EDIT: It's not actually a 'ping' that I want to do. I'm just using it as an example of a command with continuous output, which in time, I would like to terminate.

More specifically, I'm running an old version of BitTorrent (v5.0.9 from the 3rd answer here: [Where to find BitTorrent source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318969/bittorrent-source-code)) and I'm calling it via python script. The bittorrent-console.py is a simple terminal version, hence 'console'. It outputs multiple lines periodically. Something like:

```
saving:       filename
file size:    blah
percent done: 100.0
blah:         blahblah
```

I'm actually calling it by:

```
subprocess.call(['./bittorrent-console.py', 'something.torrent'])
```

I want to terminate it automatically when I see it's 100.0 in 'percent done:'.

EDIT: I'm running on CentOS, Python 2.6.

Comment: note also that `10` might be part of the IP address

Comment: Yep, I realized that, but assume there's no 10 in the address or the time. But again, just an example. It could've been `if re.search('icmp_seq=10'`.

Comment: Note that `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.call` differ in one *very* important detail. The former is asynchronous, the latter is syncrhonous. In the latter case, by the time you call `os.kill()`, the app is already dead and `os.kill()` has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Ah. Yes. That is indeed true. I want to keep on using `call` though, because there's no lag in output like when I tried the answer below. It simply has just called bittorrent-console and left it running. I don't know how to terminate it when the download's done except by Keyboard Interrupt.

Comment: Would you happen to know if inside the script, after `call`, there's a way to get the process id of what I just called?

Comment: BTW, you can share a specific answer just by using its `share` link. That's how we can look at the same answer while having different sort options (active/oldest/votes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you want to use `p.stdout.readline`. I'm not sure why, but `for line in p.stdout` doesn't seem to flush. Perhaps it's buffered.

Secondly, you should use `sys.stdout.write(line)`, because `print` always appends something. In Python 3 you can use `print(line, end="")`, though.

Also, you should prefer `p.kill` to `os.kill`. I'm not sure why you're using `os.kill`.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', 'google.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()

    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if '10' in line:
        break

p.kill()
```

Comment: I think this will do the trick. Worked for the `ping` example. I'll try it later on what I'm really working on.

Comment: This doesn't output very well. It takes time to write and flush per line since bittorrent-console prints out multiples lines at a time. Is there any way that I could just use subprocess.call, catch the '100.0' and terminate bittorrent-console?

Comment: No, there is not. You can pass `bufsize=0` to `subprocess.Popen` but there is nothing more that you can do (parsing sub-lines could help if lines are given out incrementally, but I doubt it).

Comment: Well, your answer did solve my question. I don't want the slow update on terminal output though. I need it to still look real-time. I guess I'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 2):

This does exactly what you want and works perfectly on my OS X machine:

```
import subprocess
import re

def get_output(cmd, until):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ret = []
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        ret.append(line)
        if re.search(until, line):
            break
    p.kill()
    return ret

 print ''.join(get_output(['ping', 'google.com'], until='10'))
```

Comment: Again, `10` and `ping` were just examples.

Comment: I don't see how this answer doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Sure, it does. But you iterated over a range. I wanted to terminate when I see a pattern '10'.

Comment: I thought you meant "after 10 lines of output". In any case, I've updated my answer accordingly.